# mongoid yaml combines environment variables for hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, mongoid, openshift

I am new to rails and mongoid, I have `mongoid.yml` file that contains the entries as follows:

```
development:
  # Configure available database clients. (required)
  clients:
    # Defines the default client. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: mycollectionname
      # Provides the hosts the default client can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

this works properly for development, however, in production, I'd like to specify the host from environment variables like `ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST']` + ":" + `ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT']`

I've tried various ways such as this

```
    hosts:
      - <%= \"#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_HOST']}:#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_PORT']}\" %>
```

or

```
    hosts:
      - #{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_HOST']:ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_PORT']}
```

etc, but none works

Comment: Did you also try using the URI instead, i.e. `uri: <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL'] %>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In yaml code, `<%= %>` is meant for you to insert ruby code, you can use [Expression Substitution](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_strings.htm) inside it to format your url

`Expression substitution is a means of embedding the value of any Ruby expression into a string using #{ and }`

Something like this will do:

`<%= "#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_HOST']}:#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_PORT']}" %>`

In my mongoid project with openshift, I am using its `uri:` field like this:

`uri: <%= "#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL']}#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']}" %>`

Please also pay attention to the indentation, it has to be accurate and it has to be space! Tab will cause problems too!

Comment: Mine is something like this but it doesn't seem to work; treat :27017 like a symbol. Putting it inside doesn't seem to work as well.
      hosts:
        - <%= "#{ENV['MONGODB_HOST']}" %>:27017